# Fast and efficient way to loop below code in R

Tags: r

I want to run the below loop in an efficient way as I need to perform this on millions of rows.
Sample data

```
a <- data.frame(x1=rep(c('a','b','c','d'),5),
                x2=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5),
                value1=c(rep(201,4),rep(202,4),rep(203,4),rep(204,4),rep(205,4)),
                y1=c(rep('a',4),rep('b',4),rep('c',4),rep('d',4),rep('e',4)),
                y2=c(1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5,3,4,5,6,4,5,6,7,5,6,7,8),
                value2=seq(101,120), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I wrote below to compare similar values between two columns and then find the difference.

```
for (i in 1:length(a$x1)){
  for (j in 1:length(a$x1)){
    if(a$y1[i] == a$x1[j] & a$y2[i] == a$x2[j]){
      a$diff[i] <- a$value1[j] - a$value2[i]
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding what the expected output should be, and I suspect there are issues in your for-loop. Can you edit your question to show what the output 'diff' column should look like in your example?

Comment: Are you sure the example, you provided is correct ? for example when i =15

Comment: I missed break statement which I edited it now. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: It's safer to assign the a$diff column (eg as a column of NAs) before looping, since your code initially fills the whole column with the first value (100) and then replaces values only when the condition is met. So most of the 100s in the output diff column are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For each i, you are to find the first j such that `a$y1[i] == a$x1[j] && a$y2[i] == a$x2[j]`  (in your code, there is `&` instead of `&&` which is obviously wrong).

If `a$x1`, `a$x2`, `a$y1`, `a$y2` are either numbers or character data without spaces (like in your example), you could use

```
x12 = paste(a$x1, a$x2)
y12 = paste(a$y1, a$y2)
```

then for each i, you are to find the first j such that `x12[i]==y12[j]`

You do it with `match(x12, y12)`.

So you can do something like this:

```
x12 = paste(a$x1, a$x2)
y12 = paste(a$y1, a$y2) 
m = match(x12, y12)
for (i in seql(m))
    if (!is.na(m[i]))
        a$diff[i] <- a$value1[m[i]] - a$value2[i]
```

You can eliminate the last loop like this:

```
x12 = paste(a$x1, a$x2)
y12 = paste(a$y1, a$y2) 
m = match(x12, y12)
good.i = which(!is.na(m))
a$diff[good.i] <- a$value1[m[good.i]] - a$value2[good.i]
```