# Apply functions instead of for loop in R

Tags: r, apply

I am novice in R. I want to know how we can write the below for loop in an efficient way. I am getting correct answer by the below code for small dataset.

```
data <- data.frame(x1=c(rep('a',12)),
            x2=c(rep('b',12)),
            x3=c(rep(as.Date('2017-03-09'),4),rep(as.Date('2017-03-10'),4),rep(as.Date('2017-03-11'),4)),
            value1= seq(201,212),
            x4=c(as.Date('2017-03-09'),as.Date('2017-03-10'),as.Date('2017-03-11'),as.Date('2017-03-12')
                 ,as.Date('2017-03-10'),as.Date('2017-03-11'),as.Date('2017-03-12'),as.Date('2017-03-13')
                 ,as.Date('2017-03-11'),as.Date('2017-03-12'),as.Date('2017-03-13'),as.Date('2017-03-14')),
            value2= seq(101,112), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Below for loop script:

```
for (i in 1:length(data$x3)){
  print(i)
  if (!is.na(data$x4[i])){
    if(data$x4[i] == data$x3[i] && data$x2[i]==data$x2[i] && data$x1[i]==data$x1[i]){

      data$diff[i] <- data$value1[i] - data$value2[i]
    }
    else{
      print("I am in else")
      for (j in 1:length(data$x3)){
        print(c(i,j))
        # print(a$y[i])
        if(data$x4[i]==data$x3[j] && data$x1[i]==data$x1[j] && data$x2[i]==data$x2[j]){

          # print(a$x[j])
          data$diff[i] <- data$value1[j] - data$value2[i]
          break
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Am I guessing right that this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45179763/fast-and-efficiet-way-to-loop-below-code-in-r - is the same problem?

Comment: Yes, this is quiet similar. But I  tried that code but I am not getting the right results. @thelatemail

Comment: what is the purpose of comparisons : `data$x2[i]==data$x2[i]` and `data$x1[i]==data$x1[i]` in 2nd `if` loop ? It doesn't make sense

Comment: for different x3 values, we can have same x1 and x2 values. I want to make sure that I am comparing all the values correctly. my code might not be proper.

Comment: I tried using apply function:    data$diff<-data$value1[sapply(1:NROW(data), function(i)
  which(paste(data$x1[i], data$x2[i], data$x4[i]) 
        == paste(data$x1, data$x2, data$x3))[1])] - data$value2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want performance, the answer is often Rcpp.
Translating your R code in Rcpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector f_Rcpp(List data) {

  StringVector      x1 = data["x1"]; 
  StringVector      x2 = data["x2"]; 
  NumericVector     x3 = data["x3"];
  NumericVector     x4 = data["x4"];
  NumericVector value1 = data["value1"];
  NumericVector value2 = data["value2"];

  int n = value1.size();
  NumericVector diff(n, NA_REAL);

  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    Rprintf("%d\n", i);
    if (x4[i] != NA_REAL) {
      if (x4[i] == x3[i]) {
        diff[i] = value1[i] - value2[i];
      } else {
        Rprintf("I am in else\n");
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
          Rprintf("%d %d\n", i, j);
          if (x4[i] == x3[j] && x1[i] == x1[j] && x2[i] == x2[j]) {
            diff[i] = value1[j] - value2[i];
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return diff;
}

/*** R
f_Rcpp(data)
*/
```

Put that in a .cpp file and source it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
data$diff <- sapply(seq_along(data$x3), function(i) {
  if (!is.na(data$x4[i])){
    ind <- which(data$x4[i] == data$x3 & data$x1[i] == data$x1 & data$x2[i] == data$x2)
    j <- `if`(i %in% ind, i, min(ind))
    data$value1[j] - data$value2[i]
  } else {
    NA
  }
})
```

Beware **in your code**, if column `$diff` doesn't exist yet, doing `data$diff[1] <- 100` will put all the values of the column at `100`.

Comment: This code is working fine when the data frame is small. But it is taking so much time for large data frame. I have data frame of more than 176K rows, for which it is taking forever. Is there any way to make its faster for big data frame?

Comment: The answer is Rcpp. Would you like me to update my answer?

Comment: @Kaushik I made another answer with the Rcpp alternative.